# tf.keras plot_model: add_node() received a non node class object

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm getting back into python and have been trying out some stuff with tensorflow and keras. I wanted to use the plot_model function and after sorting out some graphviz issues I am now getting this error -

> TypeError: add_node() received a non node class object:

I've tried to find an answer myself but have come up short, as the only answer I found with this error didn't seem to be to do with tf. Any suggestions or alternative ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Here's the code and error message - my first question on here so sorry if I missed anything, just let me know.

I'm using miniconda3 with python 3.8

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

from numpy import argmax
from matplotlib import pyplot
from random import randint

tf.keras.backend.set_floatx("float64")
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0
x_train = x_train[..., tf.newaxis]
x_test = x_test[..., tf.newaxis]

class mnist_model(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mnist_model, self).__init__()
        self.conv = Conv2D(32, 3, activation = tf.nn.leaky_relu, kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform', input_shape = (28, 28, 3))
        self.pool = MaxPool2D((2,2))
        self.flat = Flatten()
        self.den1 = Dense(128, activation = tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')
        self.drop = Dropout(0.25)
        self.den2 = Dense(10, activation = tf.nn.softmax)

    def call(self, inputs):
        n = self.conv(inputs)
        n = self.pool(n)
        n = self.flat(n)
        n = self.den1(n)
        n = self.drop(n)
        return self.den2(n)

model = mnist_model()

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

limit = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', patience = 5)

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs = 1, verbose = 2, validation_split = 0.15, steps_per_epoch = 100, callbacks = [limit])
print("\nTraining finished\n\nTesting 10000 samples")
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose = 1)
print("Testing finished\n")


plot_model(model, show_shapes = True, rankdir = 'LR')


##################################################################################################################################################################
                              ## Error message: ##

Train on 51000 samples, validate on 9000 samples

Training finished

Testing 10000 samples
10000/10000 [==============================] - 7s 682us/sample - loss: 0.2447 - accuracy: 0.9242
Testing finished

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\Various Python\Tensorflow\Tensorflow_experimentation\tc_mnist.py", line 60, in <module>
    plot_model(model, show_shapes = True, rankdir = 'LR')

  File "C:\Users\Thomas\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\utils\vis_utils.py", line 283, in plot_model
    dpi=dpi)

  File "C:\Users\Thomas\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\utils\vis_utils.py", line 131, in model_to_dot
    dot.add_node(node)

  File "C:\Users\Thomas\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pydotplus\graphviz.py", line 1281, in add_node
    'class object: {}'.format(str(graph_node))

TypeError: add_node() received a non node class object: <pydotplus.graphviz.Node object at 0x00000221C7E3E888>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think root-cause of the issue is with shape inference of Subclassed model where `model.summary` shows `multiple` as `Output Shape`. I added a model call within the subclassed model as shown below.

```
def model(self):
        x = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
        return Model(inputs=[x], outputs=self.call(x))
```

With this modification, shape inference is automatic in Functional API. As Functional and Sequential model as static graphs of layers, we can get the shape inference easily. However, subclassed model is a piece of python code (a call method) and there is no graph of layers to infer easily. We cannot know how layers are connected to each other (because that's defined in the body of call, not as an explicit data structure), so we cannot infer input / output shapes.

[image: Plot_model looks like]

Please check [full code here](https://github.com/jvishnuvardhan/Stackoverflow_Questions/blob/master/plot_model.ipynb) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks, this has fixed the issue. I was not aware of shape inference before but have done some reading on it now. Just out of curiosity, would you recommend the Functional API way of doing things over the subclass-ing way to avoid this kind of problem? or are their any benefits to doing it how I did it?

Comment: Shape inference is needed only for visualization as model.summary, or for plotting model, etc but subclassed model works as expected. Subclassed models give you lot of customization so you can customize layers, write your own optimizers, loss functions etc., so that you have more parameters to tune and get better performance. If you want something but TF or Keras doesn't include then you have to use subclassed models only. Writing subclassed models is little difficult but I think learning subclassed models will help you in near future.

Comment: I hadn't realised you could do so much with them! Thanks again for all your help!