# Keras.model.summary does not correctly display my model..?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to see my model's summary through keras.model.summary, but it doesn't work well.
My code is as below:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = Conv2D(32,3,activation = 'relu')
        self.flatten = Faltten()
        self.d1 = Dense(128, activation = 'relu')
        self.d2 = Dense(10, activation = 'relu')

    def trythis(self,x):
        a = BatchNormalization()
        b = a(x)
        return b

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = trythis(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.d1(x)
        return self.d2(x)

model = MyModel()
model.build((None, 32,32,3))
model.summary()
```

I expected BatchNorm layer, but summary is as below:

```
Model: "my_model_30"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_31 (Conv2D)           multiple                  896       
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_30 (Flatten)         multiple                  0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_60 (Dense)             multiple                  3686528   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_61 (Dense)             multiple                  1290      
=================================================================
Total params: 3,688,714
Trainable params: 3,688,714
Non-trainable params: 0
```

It does not contain the BatchNorm layer in 'trythis' method.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shape inference of subclassed model is not automatic as in Functional API. So I added a model call within the subclassed model and defined a functional model as shown below. Please note that there are couple ways to do and what I am showing is one way. Please check more details at similar question that I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61603966/tf-keras-plot-model-add-node-received-a-non-node-class-object/61604585#61604585)

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Dense, Flatten, BatchNormalization

class MyModel(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = Conv2D(32,3,activation = 'relu')
        self.flatten = Flatten()
        self.d1 = Dense(128, activation = 'relu')
        self.d2 = Dense(10, activation = 'relu')

    def trythis(self,x):
        a = BatchNormalization()
        b = a(x)
        return b

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = MyModel.trythis(self,x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.d1(x)
        return self.d2(x)
    def model(self):
        x = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))
        return Model(inputs=[x], outputs=self.call(x))

model = MyModel()
model_functional = model.model()
#model.build((None, 32,32,3))
model_functional.summary()
```

Summary is as follows

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_5 (InputLayer)         [(None, 32, 32, 3)]       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 30, 30, 32)        896       
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNo (None, 30, 30, 32)        128       
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_4 (Flatten)          (None, 28800)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 128)               3686528   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 10)                1290      
=================================================================
Total params: 3,688,842
Trainable params: 3,688,778
Non-trainable params: 64
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Aha.. Thank you so much! I have another question. In my original code, though keras.model.summary does not capture the model's architecture correctly, the model works as I intended?

Comment: That is expected. Only thing is shape inference is not easy as in functional and sequential model where they are static graphs. This inference is needed only for visualization as model.summary, or for plotting model, etc but subclassed model works as expected.